# Pergunta simples PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tenho essa linha em um código para conectar ao banco de dados, mas aparece o seguinte erro:

#### Código

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

#### Erro

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\bancoDespesas.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\bancoDespesas.php on line 8

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Aparentemente Está faltando parâmetros para a conexão. Abaixo está o método que eu faço.

```php
<?php 

    $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DATABASE_USER = 'root';
    $DATABASE_PASS = '';
    $DATABASE_NAME = 'nome_do_banco';

    $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        die(json_encode(array('message' => 'Falha ao Conectar ao MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error(), 'code' => 599)));
        exit('Falha ao Conectar ao MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

Aqui também tem um exemplo do proprio site do [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

```php
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Mais acredito que esse método so funcione no php5 se você estiver usando o php7 a primeira opção e melhor escolha. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: "undefined function mysql_connect()" não tem nada a ver com erro de conexão, a função é que não existe.